# Can we use a Kafka consumer to read directly from AWS Kinesis Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, amazon-kinesis

Is there a way for a Kafka consumer to read directly from an AWS Kinesis Stream?

Azure EventHub provides the option of enabling Kafka, so that a Kafka consumer can seamlessly read from EventHub. Is there something similar in AWS Kinesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not. Kafka and Kinesis use different methods of communication and have different representations of their records

You could use Kafka Connect to source data from Kinesis into Kafka, then consume from that, though